# zsh auto completes non-executable files in $PATH when press TAB

Tags: command-line, bash, zsh, auto-completion

I'm using oh-my-zsh, along with some custom scripts that automatically add sub-directories under specific folder to PATH. Taking android studio for example, assume `~/android-studio/bin` is included in PATH, press `TAB` after `studio`, zsh gives hint:

```
➜  ~ studio
studio64.vmoptions  studio.png          studio.sh           studio.vmoptions

➜  bin ll studio*
-rw-r--r-- 1 j j  559 May  26 13:44 studio64.vmoptions
-rw-r--r-- 1 j j 9.6K May  26 13:44 studio.png
-rwxr-xr-x 1 j j 6.7K May  26 13:44 studio.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 j j  566 May  26 13:44 studio.vmoptions
```

obviously only `studio.sh` is the executable that I wanted. Is there any option to prevent zsh auto complete non-executable commands?

UPDATE: tpye `studio` in home then `CTRL+X h`:

```
➜  ~ studio
tags in context :completion::complete:-command-::
    commands builtins functions aliases suffix-aliases reserved-words jobs parameters  (_command_names _autocd) 
    commands                                                                           (_path_commands _command_names _autocd) 
    jobs                                                                               (_jobs _command_names _autocd) 
    parameters                                                                         (_parameters _command_names _autocd) 
    local-directories                                                                  (_cd _autocd)
```

Comment: Does this still happen, if you are not inside `~/android-studio/bin`? Also, could you please add the output you get, when pressing `Ctrl+X h` (that is `Ctrl+X` followed by `h`) instead of `Tab` after `studio`? This should show which types of completions (commands, files, directories, etc.) *zsh* would attempt in that situation.

Comment: @Adaephon, yes this still happen when not inside android bin. I have updated the output of `CTRL+x h`.